# Reading a text file and matching it to a dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary, append, key, calculation

I have a function calculating employee salary and tax etc. that is reading from text files. My calculations are working but I want to be able to change the dictionary output based on the key value I select. I have an employee text file with salary information like:

54361 Smith Neil 37 16 1.5 70 700

23513 Kelly Alan 40 18 1.5 70 700

And an HourInfo.txt file:

54361 31/10/2021 42

23513 21/10/2021 45

I want the first value of each line, 'StaffID' to be the key I can cycle between for each employee. My code manages to do all my calculations as expected but it only outputs the information of the last employee in the Employee.txt file.

```
class Employee:
  employdata = {}

  def __init__(self, StaffID, LastName, FirstName, RegHours, HourlyRate, OTMulti, TaxCredit, StandardBand):
    self.StaffID = StaffID
    self.LastName = LastName
    self.FirstName = FirstName
    self.RegHours = RegHours
    self.HourlyRate = HourlyRate
    self.OTMulti= OTMulti
    self.TaxCredit = TaxCredit
    self.StandardBand = StandardBand
    Employee.employdata[StaffID] = self  

  @staticmethod
  def setup(employeeFile):
    with open(employeeFile) as newFile:
      for line in newFile:
        SI, LN, FN, RH, HR, OT, TC, SB = line.split()
        Employee(SI, LN, FN, int(RH), int(HR), float(OT), int(TC), int(SB))


  @staticmethod
  def computePayment(HoursWorked, date):
    d = {}
    with open('HourInfo.txt') as hoursFile:
      for line in hoursFile:
        StaffID, db, HW = line.split()
        d['Hours Worked'] = HoursWorked
        d['Regular Hours Worked'] = Employee.employdata[StaffID].RegHours
        d['Regular Rate'] = Employee.employdata[StaffID].HourlyRate
        OTMulti = Employee.employdata[StaffID].OTMulti
        d['Tax Credit'] = Employee.employdata[StaffID].TaxCredit
        StandardBand = Employee.employdata[StaffID].StandardBand
        d['Date'] = date
        d['Name'] = Employee.employdata[StaffID].FirstName + ' ' + Employee.employdata[StaffID].LastName
        d['Regular Pay'] = d['Regular Rate'] * d['Regular Hours Worked']
        if (d['Hours Worked'] > d['Regular Hours Worked']):
          d['Overtime Hours Worked'] =  d['Hours Worked'] - d['Regular Hours Worked']
        else: 
          d['Overtime Hours Worked'] = 0
        d['OverTime Rate'] = int(d['Regular Rate'] * OTMulti)
        d['OverTime Pay'] = d['Overtime Hours Worked'] * d['OverTime Rate']
        d['Gross Pay'] = d['Regular Pay'] + d['OverTime Pay']
        d['Standard Rate Pay'] = StandardBand
        if (d['Gross Pay'] > d['Standard Rate Pay']):
          d['Higher Rate Pay'] = d['Gross Pay'] - d['Standard Rate Pay']
        else:
          d['Higher Rate Pay'] = 0
        d['Standard Tax'] = int(d['Standard Rate Pay'] * 0.2)
        d['Higher Tax'] = round(d['Higher Rate Pay'] * 0.4, 2)
        d['Total Tax'] = round(d['Standard Tax'] + d['Higher Tax'], 2)
        d['Net Deduction'] = round(d['Total Tax'] - d['Tax Credit'], 2)
        d['Net Pay'] = round(d['Gross Pay'] - d['Net Deduction'], 2)

      return d

ns = Employee(54361, 'Smith', 'Neil', 37, 16, 1.5, 70, 700)
ns.setup('Employee.txt')
ns.computePayment(42, '11/11/21')
```

My output for the calculations work, but it only calculates the last line of my Employee.txt, regardless of if I try to select the information in the first line of my Employee.txt file. Dictionary output:

{'Date': '11/11/21', 'Gross Pay': 774, 'Higher Rate Pay': 74, 'Higher Tax': 29.6, 'Hours Worked': 42, 'Name': 'Alan Kelly', 'Net Deduction': 99.6, 'Net Pay': 674.4, 'OverTime Pay': 54, 'OverTime Rate': 27, 'Overtime Hours Worked': 2, 'Regular Hours Worked': 40, 'Regular Pay': 720, 'Regular Rate': 18, 'Standard Rate Pay': 700, 'Standard Tax': 140, 'Tax Credit': 70, 'Total Tax': 169.6}

Comment: In computePayment() you loop over hoursFile, get the StaffID, and update `d`. Each time through the loop you completely overwrite all the values in `d`, so only the last version remains - the last StaffID in hoursFile.